Ceiling fan old switch replacement
I am replacing the pull chain ceiling fan switch (on/off) that has a blue wire into one side and out the other. The switch that I want to use (supposedly a ceiling fan switch) in the attached information says the switch is a 3 or 4 wire switch (and gives instructions on how to remove the wires from the inside of the switch).
Since the fan is either on or off, would I connect one of the two blue leads from outside the old switch, to one of the leads of the new switch and then the other lead from the old switch to the remaining lead of the new switch?
I would then not be using the third or fourth leads from the new switch and I would then wire nut each and tape to insure no shorts from any other wires.

It does not really matter. You have a 3 speed switch on one speed fan and any wire combination will work on your on/off
